# jquery submit function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

thanks for looking.

I'm having an issue i cant seem to get the submit function workin.

load login form if needed.

```
login_box_comment = function(){
 $("body").append('<div id="login_form_modal" style="display:none">'+
'<div id="status" align="left">'+
'<center><h1><img src="/ext/login/img/key.png" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;LOGIN</h1>'+
'<div id="login_response"><!-- spanner --></div> </center>'+
'<form id="login" action="javascript:alert(\"success!\");">'+
'<input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_login">'+
'<input type="hidden" name="module" value="login">'+
'<label>Username</label><input type="text" name="user"><br />'+
'<label>Password</label><input type="password" name="password"><br />'+
'<input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="autologin" value="1">Log me on automatically each visit<br />'+
'<input type="checkbox" name="viewonline" id="viewonline" value="0">Hide my online status this session<br />'+
'<label><a href="/forum/ucp.php?mode=register">Register</a> | </label><input value="Login" name="Login" id="submit" class="big" type="submit" />'+
'<div id="ajax_loading">'+
'<img align="absmiddle" src="/ext/login/img/spinner.gif">&nbsp;Processing...'+
'</div>'+
'</form>'+
'</div>'+
'</div>');

$('#login_form_modal').modal();
}
```

and ths submit function

```
$("#status > form").submit(function(){  
alert('working');
}):
```

Comment: what exactly "does not work"?

Comment: when i press submit it should show alert: working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) handler only **after** the form has been appended to the DOM. So, you need to first make sure the `login_box_comment` function is called and only then attach the event because if the form is not present in the DOM the jQuery won't do anything:

```
login_box_comment();
$('#status > form').submit(function() {
    alert('working');
});
```

or simply attach the `submit` handler inside the `login_box_comment` function:

```
login_box_comment = function() {
    $('body').append('.......');
    $('#status > form').submit(function() {
        alert('working');
    });
    $('#login_form_modal').modal();
};
```

Comment: im really new to this so im going to research on "Adding elements to the DOM"

Comment: any chance of an example on how to do that?

Comment: Look at my second code snippet. You `.append` elements to the DOM and then you attach event handlers to them (`.submit`).