# JQuery submit function dont starts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a little problem. I have already looked at many threads like:
- [jquery submit function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075061/jquery-submit-function-not-working)
- [jQuery submit function not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572350/jquery-submit-function-not-working-properly)
- [JQuery Submit Form From Inside Submit Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964715/jquery-submit-form-from-inside-submit-function)

But I have the problem that my submit doesn't work. I don't see why.
I would be happy if someone could explain to me why the submit button doesn't work.
I don't see a log in the console **submit**.

My goal is:
1. click on a button which is not a submit button
2. do some stuff then
3. then start submit & do something there

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="submit.html" id="test">
  <input type="button" id="bttn" value="Submit"></input>
 </form>
</body>
</html>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $( 'input#bttn' ).on( 'click', function() {
        
        // do something
        
  console.log('click');
 
        // start submit
  $( 'form#test' ).submit( function() {
   console.log('submit');
   return true;
   
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your method is wrong. `method="post" action="submit.html"`

Comment: Good catch @JackNicholson!

Comment: You're using the wrong form of jquery's submit. What you're doing is binding an event handler, which will run when the submit event fires. If you want to manually trigger submit, then you have to use this instead: $('form#test').submit()

Comment: Then in my case I dont see the advantage of that, i just could do all before i use the submit trigger without the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake (no method and duplicate action): `<form action="post" action="submit.html" id="test">` should be `<form method="post" action="submit.html" id="test">`.

Second mistake:

```
$( 'form#test' ).submit( function() { // handler for submit event
    console.log('submit');
    return true;
});
```

should just be

```
$( 'form#test' ).submit(); // triggers submit event
```

And then you can add the handler for the submit event, which would be called after submit triggers:

```
$( 'form#test' ).submit( function() {
    console.log('submit');
});
```

Comment: The first mistake was copy paste I think.
So because the second mistake:
- so if i use the submit as a handler, then i need to trigger it manually?

Comment: But then I dont see the advantage of that? Because I could do all the things that i want do, before i just trigger the submit without the handler...?